# php random number code that uses same random number throughout session

Tags: php, session, random, numbers

I found a php random number generator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140235/php-random-number) which works on my Wordpress site. The actual code (see below) displays a new random number when the browser reloads. My goal is to have the same random number appears throughout the browser session.

```
$amountOfDigits = 3;
$numbers = range(0,9);
shuffle($numbers);

for($i = 0;$i < $amountOfDigits;$i++)
$digits .= $numbers[$i];

echo $digits; //prints 217356
```

What code do I add to the above so that the same random number appears throughout the browser session? I read the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642047/pseudo-random-numbers-in-php) but I'm unsure if that code would work with the code above. I also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069326/reproducible-random-number-series) as well, but it's above my head.

Comment: http://php.net/srand ?

Answer (score 1):

Stick it in a `$_SESSION` and then echo it back out.

```
[code]

session_start();     

if (!isset($_SESSION['random'])) {

    $amountOfDigits = 3;
    $numbers = range(0,9);
    shuffle($numbers);

    for($i = 0;$i < $amountOfDigits;$i++)
    $digits .= $numbers[$i];

    $_SESSION['random'] = $digits;

}
elseif (isset($_SESSION['random'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['random']; //prints 217356
}

[/code]
```

Answer (score 1):

Store it in the session...

```
function getRandom()
{
   if(isset($_SESSION['myRandomNumber'])
      return $_SESSION['myRandomNumber'];

   $amountOfDigits = 3;
   $numbers = range(0,9);
   shuffle($numbers);

   for($i = 0;$i < $amountOfDigits;$i++)
      $digits .= $numbers[$i];

   // Store in session
   $_SESSION['myRandomNumber'] = $digits

   return $digits;
 }
```

Be sure to use `session_start()` before using a function like this.